# Common LISP addition program

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I was trying to write a program that takes in a list of numbers and adds 1 to each element in the list. Similarly if the list is 0 it will return NIL. I tried doing it recursively but it shows me no output. I know it's simple but I am a beginner and its really hard for me to think about the problem recursively. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "trying to write a _program_" do you really mean "trying to write a _function_"? Further,  you said that you tried something that didn't work... if you want help with respect to _your_ solution you'd better post your current solution, otherwise no one is possibly going to give you _their_ ready-made solution.

Comment: "I tried doing it recursively but it shows me no output."  I dont' see this in your question.  Please note that **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.**

Comment: "it's simple but I am a beginner and its really hard for me to think about the problem recursively. "  Why do it recursively at all?  What's the matter with `(defun add-1 (list) (mapcar '1+ list))`?  You don't need to know how mapcar is implemented (it *could* be recursive, but that's an implementation detail).   But you could just as well `(loop for x in list collect (1+ x))`.  That's seems non-recursive (though the implementation *could* be recursive), and it works just as well.  It sounds like you're either assuming requirements, or you've got requirements that you're not stating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assignment requires you to define a recursive function (say `my-fun` for generality) to do something on every element of a list you could use this idiom

```
(cons (do-something-on (car my-list)) (my-fun (cdr my-list)))
```

where you

1. modify the 1st element
2. apply the function that you're defining to the rest of the list
3. return a list constructed joining the modified 1st element and the result of applying the function you're defining to the rest of the list

That's not all, you have to take into account what happens when you exaust the list... but that's easy, you can write a conditional that returns the default value (see above) if the list is not empty and `nil` otherwise.

```
(if my-list (...) nil)
```

or, using the default behavior of a else-less `if`,

```
(if my-list (...))
```

Answer (score 0):

A list is made of `cons`. It has the first value and a list consisting of the rest of the list except the first value. Thus you should check if your list is `null` (or `endp` which is the same) and if it isn't you make a `cons` with the calculation you have with the `first` and the recursive call using the `rest`. as argument.

```
(add-1 '(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))) ; ==> (2 . (3 . (4 . ())))
```

Or more commonly written:

```
(add-1 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (2 3 4)
```